# IBAN number correct but name has extra space between two letters

Tags: iban

I have transfered my tuition fees to Finland. The IBAN is correct. However, the name has extra space between two letters it should be `abc` now it is `ab` `c` in this format. What can happen now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can happen now?

This depends on the Bank where the credit is happening. Generally most Banks don't verify the Name. The transfer is done solely on the IBAN. So it should go through. Some Bank would verify the name and generally cater for spaces; i.e. they would remove all spaces and compare the values ... else worst thing, it get returned.

Comment: I got a computer generated copies of info that my fund has been transfered. Yet no confirmation from other side. Finish IBAN is 18 character. I have all 18 character correctly. However, they put no space between last two characters. Anyway, the IBAN is correct and I hope they have some system to correctly write down or format the IBAN while sending the money. @Dheer

Comment: @Jhon If you put space between IBAN or don't put a space; it doesn't matter; most systems handle these correctly. I was thinking space issue in Account Name and not IBAN.